# Change Element's node name?

Tags: html, dom, gwt

Is it possible to change the element's node name in GWT? I mean something like this:

```
HTML h = new HTML();
h.getElement().setNodeName("mydiv")
```

while there is no `setNodeName()` method for `Element`.

I'd like to acquire `<mydiv>some contents</mydiv>` instead of default tag `<div>some contents</div>`

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the element node name of the `HTML` widget. However, you can create your own tag with `Document.get().createElement("mydiv")`, and use that to create a new `Widget` by extending `Composite`. However, I'm not sure why you want to do this, because adding new tags to the DOM and thereby extending HTML doesn't sound as something you should want. Setting the content in this tag isn't possible via methods like `innerText` because they are only available for valid tags.

Answer (score 1):

change the tag name while keeping content and attributes

```
function changeTagName(elm,new_tag_name){
  var newElm = document.createElement(new_tag_name)
  var atr = elm.attributes;       
  for(var i=0;i<atr.length;i++){  // copy all atributtes
     newElm.setAttribute(atr[i].name,atr[i].value)
  } 
  document.body.insertBefore(newElm,elm)
  newElm.innerHTML=elm.innerHTML; //copy the content
  elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm)  // remove original 
}
```

for example:

```
<span id='sp1' class='cl1 cl2'> some t  e x t with   (\n)         gaps .... and etc</span>

changeTagName(document.getElementById('sp1'),'pre');
```